# Silverlight WSOD at remote client site

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I have a client who installed our silverlight app recently.  it works fine from their server itself.  but when they try to run it from a client, they can log in through the aspx login page, but on the main page, which hosts the  tag and the .xap file, they see absolutely nothing!

I cannot see their screens, just get occasional screenshots via email and cross my fingers that they are typing the URL I tell them to.  Even Shareview is not working for them - they can see my screen but I cannot see theirs.

So I am pleading - help!  Please throw out some wacky ideas.   I just learned an hour or so ago that they did not even have silverlight installed, so the mornings debugging effort was a waste of time. So who knows what the next fascinating source of problems is?

Here is the user-agent info.  Oor app is .net 4.0  could that be the problem?  It does noty look to my untrained eye that the client supports 4.0 (from the web server log):

Mozilla/4.0+(compatible;+MSIE+7.0;+Windows+NT+5.1;+.NET+CLR+1.1.4322;+.NET+CLR+2.0.50727;+.NET+CLR+3.0.04506.30;+.NET+CLR+3.0.04506.648;+.NET+CLR+3.0.4506.2152;+.NET+CLR+3.5.30729) 401 3 5 0

Getting closer - I see that the GET request for the XAP is returning 401 - not found!  What would do that?

Comment: .NET 4.0 is not the problem.  The Silverlight plug-in users install is a subset of the .NET Framework without any dependence on other .NET Frameworks being present in the OS.  As long as you set your project up correctly, the minRuntimeVersion param of your instantiation of the plugin will match what you built your project with.

Comment: Yes Nissan, that makes perfect sense.  Obvious now.  I was clutching at straws.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very possible that they are blocking XAP files either directly or indirectly at the firewall.  XAP files are simply ZIP files and inspection-based firewalls tend to look at these as a security risk.  You may want to see if they can setup an exception in their rules.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm..

1) check if your client access the good url. Request their IP address, then check the web server logs. ie: are they requesting the good url, are they downloading the xap? (check if they use a proxy, too?)

2) check that they restarted their browser after installing the Silverlight runtime.

3) Do you handle the UnhandledException event for your Application class? If no, use it to send detailed exception logs to your server on application crash.

4) Use [javascript](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc265155%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)to initialize your Silverlight application. This way, you can be notified if the runtime fail to start, (for example if it failed to load the xap file) You can use ajax to report the issue to the webserver.

Comment: Mozilla/4.0+(compatible;+MSIE+7.0;+Windows+NT+5.1;+.NET+CLR+1.1.4322;+.NET+CLR+2.0.50727;+.NET+CLR+3.0.04506.30;+.NET+CLR+3.0.04506.648;+.NET+CLR+3.0.4506.2152;+.NET+CLR+3.5.30729) 401 3 5 0

Comment: Bingo - the XAP is not being downloaded.  Any ideas why it is blocked?  getting a 401 on the request for XAP

Comment: @Daniel, see my post below which has been there since you first put this question out.  A 401 error means you are not authorized to download that resource.  This would happen if the firewall blocked it.  An easy way to test this would be to have a user type in the URL of your XAP file directly from their browser to see what happens.  e.g. http://somewebsite.com/ClientBin/SomeProject.XAP

Comment: @Nissan Fan - bingo :) access denied. I wouldn't have thought about proxy filtering at first sight. Blocking zip contents is rather... extreme.

Comment: XAP/Zip files are actually viewed as a big risk by IT Sec since people often try to bypass firewall rules around sending of EXEs and other potentially malicious file types using them.

Comment: The client claims that this is not the issue.  They are also going home now (public agency).  They say that Monday I will finally be able to remote into their system so I can see first hand just what the heck they are doing.  Thank you both very much.